# I want to stop propagation by clicking a button...in this code i can do the action by checkbox but i want to do the same action by clicking button

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
div {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<h1>The stopPropagation() Method</h1>

<p>Click DIV 1:</p>
<div onclick="func2()">DIV 2
  <div onclick="func1(event)">DIV 1</div>
</div>

Stop propagation:
<input type="checkbox" id="check"> <br><br>

<button id="btn">Stop propagation</button>


<script>

function func1(event) {
  alert("DIV 1");
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function func2() {
  alert("DIV 2");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>

I want to stop propagation by clicking a button...in this code i can do the action by checkbox but i want to do the same action by clicking button...so what should i write..?
```

Comment: Not sure what you want, the "input" tag, "button" tag are in same level with div2, they are not  nested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a click counter. Like this:

```
let btn_click = false;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  btn_click = true;
}
```

And also, use the value of the variable `btn_click` in the if condition:

```
...
if (document.getElementById("check").checked || btn_click == true) {
...
```

```js
let btn_click = false;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  btn_click = true;
}

function func1(event) {
  alert("DIV 1");
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked || btn_click == true) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function func2() {
  alert("DIV 2");
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h1>The stopPropagation() Method</h1>

<p>Click DIV 1:</p>
<div onclick="func2()">DIV 2
  <div onclick="func1(event)">DIV 1</div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="check"> <br><br>
<button id="btn">Stop propagation</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sergey kuznetsov...you are awesome.

Comment: Thank. My friend was glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want say, but try this, might help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
div {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<h1>The stopPropagation() Method</h1>

<p>Click DIV 1:</p>
<div onclick="func2()">DIV 2
  <div >DIV 1</div>
</div>

Stop propagation:
<input type="checkbox" id="check"> <br><br>

<button id="btn" onclick="func1(event)" >Stop propagation</button>


<script>

function func1(event) {
  alert("DIV 1");
  if (document.getElementById("check").checked) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}

function func2() {
  alert("DIV 2");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```